# Can anyone explain this jQuery plugin to me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

How does **[this](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery-i18n-1.0.0.js.txt)** plugin works in translating to other language.

I want to use this plugin for translating language. How it works and I need the documentation for this plugin. Where can I get it.?
  Any suggestions please>

Comment: There are comments inside the code itself, they should be enough for you to use it. Unless you want to understand how it works rather than actually use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't seem to find any documentation for this plugin (but others seem to have). And the homepage provided in the code is offline.

As I don't really want analyse the code I suggest you use the [jQuery Localisation plugin](http://keith-wood.name/localisation.html) instead which is in part reused in the plugin you mention in your question but has some nice documentation and examples

Comment: ok I wil read the documentation regarding localization. But i cant understand how to use this plugin without understanding

Comment: Do you really need to use the plugin you linked too? Can't you just use the jQuery localization plugin I linked too which has some documentation which explains how to use it?